# How to check a particular attribute is present in any edge of complete traversal in ArangoDB

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, aql

In below query if i want to check wether the hs_codes mentioned in third condition of Filter is present in any level of traversal from 1st to 6th edge ,query checks for match on every edge

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..6 INBOUND 'company_node_20_02_23/60673bced674d38fcc9c438f' 
                    GRAPH graph_correct
    OPTIONS {bfs: true, uniqueVertices: 'global', maxIterations: 100000}
    FILTER p.edges[*].actual_arrival_date ALL >= '2021-04' AND
           p.edges[*].actual_arrival_date ALL <= '2021-05' AND
           p.edges[*].hs_codes  == '120400' 
    RETURN p
```

I was expecting to get all the path having date between '2021-04' and '2021-05' and any edge contains attribute '120400'

Answer (score 0):

The documentation handles this [in the Graph Traversals section](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/graphs-traversals.html#filter-on-the-entire-path), just add `ANY` to your `hs_codes` filter:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..6 INBOUND 'company_node_20_02_23/60673bced674d38fcc9c438f' 
                    GRAPH graph_correct
    OPTIONS {bfs: true, uniqueVertices: 'global', maxIterations: 100000}
    FILTER p.edges[*].actual_arrival_date ALL >= '2021-04' AND
           p.edges[*].actual_arrival_date ALL <= '2021-05' AND
           p.edges[*].hs_codes  ANY == '120400' 
    RETURN p
```